# Heros demo wont run

Tags: angular

Been a few years since working with Angular so I thought I would just go through a demo again, the tour of heros. https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4 
Downloaded the latest Angular CLI and installed typescript:

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular   <error>
@angular-devkit/core            13.3.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.4 (cli-only)
@angular/cli                    13.3.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular             13.3.4 (cli-only)
rxjs                            6.6.7 (cli-only)
typescript                      4.6.4 (cli-only)
```

Using VS Code, opened a terminal and used npm install to refresh my modules, but got this dump of errors.  Help?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angular.io-example@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: rxjs@7.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/rxjs
npm ERR!   rxjs@"~7.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer rxjs@"^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0" from @angular/common@13.3.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!     @angular/common@"~13.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@">=8.0.0" from angular-in-memory-web-api@0.11.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api
npm ERR!       angular-in-memory-web-api@"~0.11.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (@angular/core)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer rxjs@"^6.0.0" from angular-in-memory-web-api@0.11.0
npm ERR! node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api
npm ERR!   angular-in-memory-web-api@"~0.11.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

package.json
This is directly via downloading from the Angular.io website
https://angular.io/generated/zips/toh-pt4/toh-pt4.zip

```
{
  "name": "angular.io-example",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Example project from an angular.io guide.",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.11.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "jasmine-marbles": "~0.8.3",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: So is this an old thing you had laying around..? I’m confused as to what project you have here? If this is an old angular project, you’ll have to update it first I guess (since you’re using cli v13)..

Comment: I just downloaded the sample project right off the Angular.io website

Comment: Right. Then run npm install and you should be ready to go. I don’t understand the ‘download angular cli and rxjs’ parts though..? Can you post your package.json ?

Comment: Yes, and running npm install was what generated that error dump.  Package.json listed above now.

Comment: Strange. Maybe the demo isn’t uo to date but that would be a first. You can try to run npm i —force and see if that solves it.  If you happen to have a direct link to that download repo, I’d like to try myself  as this needs to be working correctly (if not, I’ll raise an issue with the angular team)..

Comment: Ps: instead of —force, you could also try to run npm i @rxjs@6

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well (using the tutorial code from https://angular.io/generated/zips/universal/universal.zip and https://angular.io/tutorial - https://angular.io/generated/zips/toh-pt6/toh-pt6.zip).

Using `npm i --force` helps to install the packages, however the warnings stay.
As @MikeOne suggests, using `npm i rxjs@6` actually installs the missing version and fixes the problem.